# I cannot clear my session after logout in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

when I try to logout in symfony2 my session support to be cleared completely
but if I click the browser back button I can get get to my previous session

```
 firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /hrs/applyleave/
        logout: 
            path: /logout
            target: /login
            path: security_admin_logout
            target: security_admin_login
            invalidate_session: true
            delete_cookie:~
        security: true
        anonymous: true
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Doesn't the logout need to be behind the firewall? What happens when you click back on the browser and then refresh the page?

Comment: after logout if I click the browser back button I can get back to the
same page but if I refresh it logs me out

but I'm thinking it should not allow me to go back in the first place!!!

Answer (score 5):

I recently came across this little problem, and with the help of a couple posts I came up with the following solution.

To clarify the issue here, after logging out of a secured area we want to prevent any secured previous pages from being viewable again by clicking the back button. To do this, those previous pages must not be stored in the clients cache. We need to intercept every Symfony page response, check if its a secured page and if so, set the headers to return no-cache.

**Step one**, set up a response listener class:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($this->disableThisPageCache($request->getPathInfo())) {
            $headers = $event->getResponse()->headers;
            $headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
            $headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
            $headers->set('Expires', '0'); // Proxies.
        }
    }

    private function disableThisPageCache($currentPath)
    {
        $paths = array('/admin', '/customer');

        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if ($this->checkPathBegins($currentPath, $path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function checkPathBegins($path, $string)
    {
        return substr($path, 0, strlen($string)) === $string;
    }
}
```

**Step 2**, register it as a service:

```
app.filter_response_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
```

**Step 3**, set the `$paths` array to contain the secured path(s) for your application. If you need to find out these, look in your security.yml file under the access_control section.

There is probably a better way of checking if the page is in a secured area, using the Symfony Security service, but this solution works for my application.

Credit to these posts that helped me:

- [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)
- http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-create-a-response-filter-and-set-extra-response-headers/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cache control directives to not load the page from the browser cache:

```
    $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->setContent($this->renderView(YOUR_VIEW));
    $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
    $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
    $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
    $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
```

Comment: thank it make perfect sense!! I will give a try and see
but where do I place this snippet  in the logout route
or some where else ....

Comment: I guess you need to add a hook that's executed after each controller. Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event from Symfony's documentation.